# web2py validators with dependencies using validated data

Tags: python, web2py

This example of a *validator with dependencies* is  provided in the web2py book in the chapter, 
[Forms and validators](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07#Validators-with-dependencies) .

```
def index():
    form = SQLFORM.factory(
        Field('username', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
        Field('password', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
        Field('password_again',
              requires=IS_EQUAL_TO(request.vars.password)))
    if form.process().accepted:
        pass # or take some action
    return dict(form=form)
```

The dependency on `password_again` is based on the raw input for the password field that is received from the form - `request.vars.password` .

What is the cleanest way to add a validator that is based on the validated data from a form, eg `form.vars.pasword` ?

I am thinking in the instance where the value in the field may be sanitised during the validation process (eg, turned to upper case, stripped of leading whitespace, have a checkdigit appended).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, use an [`onvalidation` function](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07#onvalidation).

Comment: Thanks Anthony. That's exactly the kind of approach that I was after.